# Should there be a space before and after an ampersand when writing numerals?

Tags: conjunctions, writing-style, spacing, ampersand

How should one write "one and two" in short form - **1&2** or **1 & 2**? Are there any particular rules regarding this?

In context:

> - You may choose to do Information Technology Units [1&2/1 & 2] and then IT Apps Units [3&4/3 & 4] for VCE.
> - Chapters [1&2/1 & 2] of the book give the reader an idea of the protagonist's personality.

I had a look at this [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36819/is-it-ever-appropriate-to-use-a-space-before-and-after-an-ampersand) and, whilst it had helpful and informative answers, it did not provide any detail on the usage of an ampersand to combine numerals.

Comment: I would have to say it's a matter of style. What looks best to you? Or does your employer favor a particular style guide? Personally, I don 't like it either way—it's too tight without spaces, and too loose with them—so I put spaces in, and then tighten the kerning to decrease the space. I don't know if you'd want to go to that bother.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock To be honest, it's hard to say. I really can't decide! It's one of those interesting situations where, as you said, both options look, let's say, a bit iffy.

Comment: Well actually, that question does help because where the terms are separate words like Tate, Lyle, Marks, Spencer, there is a space. Where the **whole thing** is a name, like M&S or 1&1, there aren't spaces. With chapter numbers, each is separate, so the spaces are needed. But I would prefer to use *and* spelled out in that case, anyway.

Comment: As @BrianHitchcock said, it depends on the *kerning* of the font used, and you can adjust even that.