# What is the rule for spacing between words and the character &?

Tags: punctuation, spacing

What is the rule for spacing between words and the character &? For example, do I have to space Espresso&Tonic - Espresso & Tonic, although I am talking about one drink made with an espresso and tonic? Thanks

Comment: Treat the ampersand (&) just as any other "word." That should resolve the issue.

Comment: @user070221 No. Think again.

Answer (score 0):

If the two subjects in question are separate words or acronyms, then spacing on either end of the ampersand is required.

Examples:

[HTML & CSS](https://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/htmlcss), an article by the World Wide Web Consortium.

[image: Smith & Wesson]

[Smith & Wesson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_%26_Wesson)

[image: Dolce & Gabbana]

[Dolce & Gabbana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolce_%26_Gabbana)

[image: Tiffany & Co.]

[Tiffany & Co.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiffany_%26_Co.)

Therefore, *Espresso&Tonic* is not appropriate. The correct version would be **Espresso & Tonic**.

---

[However, if the two elements are acronyms and they themselves form an acronym when used with the ampersand, then no spacing is allowed on either end of the symbol](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/36824/192087).

Examples:

[image: AT&T]

[AT&T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AT%26T)

[image: H&M]

[H&M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%26M)

[image: A&E]

[A&E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%26E_(TV_channel))